# how to embed a watermark on an image using edge in matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

in a school project i would like to do the following step to have a watermaked image in matlab

- extract the edges from an image
- insert a mark on this edge
- reconstruct the image
- extract the mark

could some one give me a link to have a good idea how to do it or help me to do that?
thank you in advance

Comment: Really, can't you just Google it? I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28140-simple-watermark-embedding-system) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-6GKSO7/index.html?product=IP&solution=1-6GKSO7)...

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a watermark to an image? Why not just overlay the whole thing.

if you have an image

```
img = imread('myimage.jpg')
wm  = imread('watermark.jpg')
```

You can just resize the watermark to the size of the image

```
wm_rs = imresize(wm, [size(img,1) size(img,2)], 'lanczos2');

img_wm(wm_rs ~= 0) = wm_rs; %This sets non-black pixels to be the watermark. (You'll have to slightly modify this for color images)
```

If you want to put it on the edges of the image, you can extract them like this

edges = edge(rgb2gray(img),'canny')

Then you can set the pixels where the edges exist to be watermark pixels

```
img_wm = img;
img_wm(edges ~= 0) = wm_rs(edges~=0);
```

Instead of direct assignment you can play around with using a mix of the img and wm_rs pixel values if you want transparency.

You'll probably have to adjust some of what I said to color images, but most should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is a nice and simple example how you can embed watermarks using MATLAB (in the spatial domain): http://imageprocessingblog.com/digital-watermarking/

Answer (score 0):

see example below(R2017b or later release):

```
% your params
img = imread('printedtext.png');
Transparency = 0.6;
fontColor = [1,1,1]; % RGB,range [0,1]
position = [700,200];

%% add  watermark
mask = zeros(size(img),'like',img);
outimg = insertText(mask,position,'china', ...
    'BoxOpacity',0,...
    'FontSize',200,...
    'TextColor', 'white');
bwMask = imbinarize(rgb2gray(outimg));
finalImg = labeloverlay(img,bwMask,...
    'Transparency',Transparency,...
    'Colormap',fontColor);
imshow(finalImg)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).