# Add file name to an image - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I wish to add to the bottom of an image another image (with the same width) which contains the image file name (basically, merging two images). How can I do it with Matlab version prior to 2014?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726071/how-to-embed-a-watermark-on-an-image-using-edge-in-matlab http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/67364-how-can-i-watermark-an-image http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102312-is-it-possible-to-add-a-timestamp-watermark-to-my-image-in-matlab-7-6-r2008a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two 3d matricies and you need to append one to the bottom of the other.  Pretty straightforward to do:

```
img1 = cat(3, rand(50, 50), rand(50,50), rand(50,50)); % Placeholder for image file data
img2 = ones(10, 50, 3); % Placeholder for text-containing image
img3 = [img1; img2]; % Stick them together
imshow(img3); % Show the generated image (here color noise with a white bar at the bottom)
```

Edit: An actual image may well be in uint8 or uint16 rather than the MATLAB-default double class.  For this your image containing text needs to be in the same class.  The class can be specified in the call to the ones() function.

```
img1 = imread('c:\path\to\class\imgName.tif');
imgCls = class(img1); % determine class of loaded image
[height, width] = size(img1);
img2 = ones(FNameHeight, width, 3, imgCls); 
img3 = [img1; img2];
imshow(img3);
```

To get, say, a black bar at the bottom of your image with the file name on it (and without extra files or the Computer Vision Toolbox), you'd do something like this:

```
imgFileName = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\koala.jpg';
img1 = imread(imgFileName);
imgCls = class(img1); % determine class of loaded image
[height, width, depth] = size(img1);

BarHeight = 20; % Height of black bar in pixels
blackBar = zeros(BarHeight, width, 3);
tempImg = figure();
tempAxes = axes('Parent', tempImg);
imshow(blackBar, 'Parent', tempAxes);
text(5, 1, imgFileName, 'color', 'w', 'VerticalAlignment', 'top', 'Interpreter', 'none');
textFrame = getframe(tempAxes);
close(tempImg);
img2 = cast(textFrame.cdata(:, 1:width, :), imgCls);

img3 = [img1; img2];
imshow(img3);
```

So to run through the procedure for the new block of code:

1. Set the height to make the text bar (20 looks good for default font)
2. Make a zeros matrix of that size
3. Make a figure and axes to hold the temporary figure.  Always good to be explicit for these rather than rely on 'gca' and 'gcf'.
4. Show black bar in your new axes.
5. Put some text over top of the black bar.  Here you can play with the first two values to change position, as well as the usual text() properties.  The 'Interpreter' property keeps MATLAB from trying to impose LaTeX on a file path, which could lead to overly interesting results.
6. Use getframe() to pull out the pseudo-image that you've created in your axes.
7. Close the temporary figure.
8. Pull out the image data you got in the getframe() call, making sure it's the right width and to cast it into the same class as the image you're going to stick this onto the bottom of.

Then proceed as before to stick this bar onto your new image and display the text-appended image.

Comment: Thanks, since there are class differences when I use a real image what do I have to fix? Furthermore how can I put text in the img2?

Code:
image = imread('C:\Users\Winzar\Desktop\a.jpg');
[height, width] = size(image);

img2 = ones(height, width, 3); 
img3 = [image; img2];  
imshow(img3);

Comment: Forgot to deal with class before, but that's easy to fix.  See edit for how to deal with this and create the text-containing image.